# Using offset for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 lines of code that I need to reproduce about 180 times. With each line (or group of lines) I need do adjust just a few numbers. It is super tedious to do with replace. Is there a way to do this with offset or something like that? Here is the code:

```
If Target.Address = "$E$7" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("F10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$8" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("G10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$9" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("H10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$10" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("I10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$11" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("J10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$12" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("K10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$13" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$14" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$15" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("N10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$16" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("O10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$17" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("P10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$18" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Q10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$19" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("R10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$20" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("S10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$21" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("T10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$22" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("U10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$23" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("V10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$24" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("W10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$25" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("X10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$26" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Y10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$27" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z6").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z7").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z8").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z9").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("Z10").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
```

So the 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 are replaced with 15, 16, 17, 18, and 19 in the next grouping. Then there is another 6 sets of the above code. Is there a way to implement some sort of offset so I can only adjust that and the rest will balance? It will always be five consecutive numbers so a single offset to would work to get to the correct starting point. An aside - the offset will not always be equal to 9 (ie. 6 becoming 15). One of the offsets will be a different number so I'd like to be able to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Is this code in an event handler, and is "budget Hours" the sheet with the code?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I don't know what an event handler is (sorry but not very good or efficient with VBA as you can see). The code is actually a `Private Sub` on a sheet called Schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what triggers the next "grouping" but here's a different appraoch.

Untested:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, msg, i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Budget Hours")

Set rng1 = ws.Range("E6:E10")
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, target.Row - 6)

msg = rng2.EntireColumn.Cells(3).Value & vbNewLine
For i = 1 To rng1.Cells.count
    msg = msg & vbNewLine & rng1.Cells(i).Value & " - " & rng2.Cells(i).Value & " Hours"
Next i

MsgBox msg, , ws.Range("E5").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it is almost perfect. I had to do some adjustments for the next "grouping" and still something doesn't work. I will post as an answer below if you are able to help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they will continue to all follow the same pattern, where `target.row` correlates to the ending column this should work.

Take the `.row` from `target` and subtract one to get your new column.

```
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(3, target.Row - 1).Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E6").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(6, target.Row - 1).Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E7").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(7, target.Row - 1).Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E8").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(8, target.Row - 1).Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E9").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(9, target.Row - 1).Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E10").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Cells(10, target.Row - 1).Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E5").Value
```

Now you shouldn't need any `if statements`.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted for what @TimWilliams said above. I now tried to make it work for my second grouping but it doesn't quite work. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Calculate

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, list As Range, msg, i As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Budget Hours")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Schedule")

'Phase 01
Dim rngPH1 As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Set rngPH1 = ws2.Range("E7:E27")
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("E6:E10")
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, Target.Row - 6)

For Each list In rngPH1
    msg = rng2.EntireColumn.Cells(3).Value & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To rng1.Cells.Count
        msg = msg & vbNewLine & rng1.Cells(i).Value & " - " & rng2.Cells(i).Value & " Hours"
    Next i
Next list

MsgBox msg, , ws1.Range("E5").Value

'Phase 02
Dim rngPH2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
Set rngPH2 = ws2.Range("E43:E63")
Set rng3 = ws1.Range("E15:E19")
Set rng4 = rng3.Offset(0, Target.Row - 36)

For Each list In rngPH2
    msg = rng4.EntireColumn.Cells(3).Value & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To rng1.Cells.Count
        msg = msg & vbNewLine & rng3.Cells(i).Value & " - " & rng4.Cells(i).Value & " Hours"
    Next i
Next list

MsgBox msg, , ws1.Range("E14").Value

End Sub
```

So my problem is that I want the Phase 01 stuff to only work on the range `Schedule("E7:E27")`. The Phase 02 stuff I want only to work on the range `Schedule("E43:E63")`. I thought by using `rngPH1` and `rngPH2` I could accomplish this but it didn't work. If I click in say `Schedule("E8")`, it brings up the correct stuff from `ws1` perfectly, but then carries on to the Phase 02 stuff which I don't want. How do I get it to do the Phase 01 stuff only on the range `rngPH1` and the Phase 02 stuff only on the range `rngPH2`?

Comment: `If not application.intersect(Target, rngPH1) Is Nothing Then` - do phase 1.  Similar for phase 2